# How do I create a separate route as a PWA in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have created a simple create-react-app. My aim is to have a separate route(endpoint) say 'localhost/pwa' to act as a PWA page(app). Most of the articles I found online talks about converting an entire React app into a PWA(which is not my use case).

I tried manipulating the index.html by adding a service worker file to it. But, not able to isolate an endpoint as a PWA as the entire app is getting rendered inside the index.html.

Thanks

Comment: What would be your usecase?

Comment: I can share this url (or endpoint) to the users, and once they access it through say phone, it can act as a PWA.

Comment: So, you means that on mobile, when they open `localhost/pwa`, it open the installed pwa. And when they open `localhost/others`, it wont open the installed pwa but open the browser instead?

Comment: Yes for others, it must work like a normal web app. For mobile users, users must be able to install it like a pwa. Even in desktop, when we access that particular url, option to install it must be there

Comment: Does the `/pwa` interacts with other link? Like share components, data, href link to other? What if `/pwa` redirect to others? will it suddently open browser? What preventing you to create separated codebase with /pwa standalone

Comment: I am planning to reuse components from the existing web app into the /pwa route. So yes, there will sharing of components and data. I am trying to figure out a way to create a pwa route without a separately deployed app.